# How do you convert a 3D position to a 2D point on screen?

Tags: java, 3d, 2d, lwjgl

I am attempting to render 2D text in the 3D environment, but to do that I need to be able to convert a set of 3D coordinates to a 2D point on the screen. My camera has a view projection matrix, a field of view, and a position in 3D space. The text I am attempting to render has a 2D point on screen.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public final Vector2f get2DPointFrom3DPosition(Vector3f position) {//position is the point in 3D space that I'm trying to render the text at
    final Vector3f camPos = this.getTransform().getPos();//where Vector3f == (x, y, z), and is a 3D position in space
    final Matrix4f viewProjection = this.getViewProjection();//where Matrix4f == float[][]
    final double fov = this.getFieldOfView();//usually 70.0f
    float X;
    float Y;
    //complicated math that I can't find with google or figure out
    return new Vector2f(X, Y);//where vector2f is a pixel position on the screen
}
```

I apologize in advance if I have missed a similar question or if I have been unclear with anything. I did find this question, but it's not in java and I can't find the underlying math going on: [Projecting a 3D point to a 2D screen position issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143207/projecting-a-3d-point-to-a-2d-screen-position-issue)

Comment: You can try [this tutorial](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html). It's about converting a 2D vector to 3D coordinates, but the steps can easily be reversed.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to reverse the process, and I don't see a matrix anywhere... brain.exe has stopped working. lol

Comment: Which mathematics library are you using?

Comment: The diagram at the top shows how to get from space to space - you have to follow the arrows going counter-clockwise. You don't need a model matrix (you already have the 3D position), `viewProjection` probably contains the view and projection matrix. Whether you have to do perspective division depends on the maths library you are using. Conversion to viewport space should then be straightforward.

Comment: The mathematics library is one made by thebennybox(https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEETnX-uPtBXP_B2yupUKlflXBznWIlL5) with Vector3f, Quaternions and Matrix4f. Other than that I use the java Math class. Thanks for all the help, I'll see if I can figure it out from here.

Comment: Well I was able to do the 2D to 3D process and the reverse, but they only return a vector3f with values ranging from -1 to 1. I need something that returns actual world coordinates and screen points.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to render some kind of menu text you could just switch to orthographic projection and then render the text. Or do you want text to appear in the scene? Then you should have a look at billboards.

Comment: And for getting the 3D to 2D conversion you have to get the ModelViewProjection matrix and feed it the 3D Point.[See here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/)

Comment: can u show ur run loop?

Comment: Here: http://redsandbox.no-ip.org/Main_Loop.java

Comment: And the render method: http://redsandbox.no-ip.org/Main_Render.java Sorry if that's not specific enough, the actual rendering takes place in my block class, and they are organized in chunks, regions, and worlds.

Answer (score 0):

```
2D_X = 3D_X / Z
2D_Y = 3D_Y / Z
```

This calculation should at least set you in the right direction methamatically speaking.